# Unable to match stringified JSON to regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with Javascript. I am generating a series of JSONs which contain some dynamically generated keys. I am trying to see whether each JSON fits a template by stringifying it using JSON.stringify() and then comparing it to a regex expression. When I console.log() the stringified JSON and compare the string to my regex expression using test(), it returns correctly (i.e. “true”). However, when I set the stringified JSON to a variable and then compare that variable to my regex expression, it returns “false” — even though the variable and the output of console.log() are same. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
//converting JSON into string

const actualFormJSONString = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync("/tmp/test form", "utf8"))

const testString = /^"{\n  \"form\": {\n    \"1\": {\n      \"type\": \"md\",\n      \"opts\": {\n        \"text\": \"example text\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"2\": {\n      \"type\": \"radio\",\n      \"opts\": {\n        \"values\": \[\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"([a-z0-9]{10,11})\",\n            \"v\": \"test option one\"\n          },\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"([a-z0-9]{10,11})\",\n            \"v\": \"test option two\"\n          },\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"([a-z0-9]{10,11})\",\n            \"v\": \"test option three\"\n          }\n        ]\n      },\n      \"q\": \"example question\?\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"order\": \[\n    \"1\",\n    \"2\"\n  ],\n  \"version\": 1\n}"$/

//produces 'false'
console.log(testString.test(actualFormJSONString))

//however if I print the actualFormJSONString variable to console and then copy/pase that into another variable, the comparison with regex works correctly 

const formJSONString = "\"{\n  \"form\": {\n    \"1\": {\n      \"type\": \"md\",\n      \"opts\": {\n        \"text\": \"example text\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"2\": {\n      \"type\": \"radio\",\n      \"opts\": {\n        \"values\": [\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"358pmuqioap\",\n            \"v\": \"test option one\"\n          },\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"5jk7dk256nr\",\n            \"v\": \"test option two\"\n          },\n          {\n            \"uid\": \"79tsbp58vgf\",\n            \"v\": \"test option three\"\n          }\n        ]\n      },\n      \"q\": \"example question?\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"order\": [\n    \"1\",\n    \"2\"\n  ],\n  \"version\": 1\n}\""

//produces 'true'
console.log(testString.test(formJSONString))
```

Comment: I bet it's a white space issue. In JSON, white space does not matter and you should never compare 2 json strings directly (a space or a newline in one of them and BANG!). Instead parse them into objects and compare those.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, you need to avoid manually adding the escape characters in formJSONString. Instead, you can create a valid JSON object and then use JSON.stringify to generate the string. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const formJSONObject = {
  form: {
    1: {
      type: "md",
      opts: {
        text: "example text",
      },
    },
    2: {
      type: "radio",
      opts: {
        values: [
          { uid: "358pmuqioap", v: "test option one" },
          { uid: "5jk7dk256nr", v: "test option two" },
          { uid: "79tsbp58vgf", v: "test option three" },
        ],
      },
      q: "example question?",
    },
  },
  order: ["1", "2"],
  version: 1,
};

const formJSONString = JSON.stringify(formJSONObject);

// Now testString.test(formJSONString) should produce 'true'
console.log(testString.test(formJSONString));
```